# Refresh sum values gets trough VBA macro in Excel by changing values in range

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I use this code to calculate sum in VBA. Code is working but how i could arrange that when i chage values in my Range also  calculate sum will be update.

Here is code:

```
Sub RangeSum()

Dim rg_1 As Range
Dim rg_2 As Range
Dim order As Range
Dim Bestand As Range
  Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row - 6
    End With
    
    Set rg_1 = Range("W6:W" & LastRow)
    Set rg_2 = Range("X6:X" & LastRow)
    Set order = Range("W4")
    Set Bestand = Range("X4")
    order = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rg_1)
    Bestand = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rg_2)
 
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the SUM formula?! If you must use code, look into the `worksheetchange` event.

Comment: I am new this, i try to have Sum of range that will change in some period with new rows, and i do not want to change  range every time. If you have any good advice i will be thankful.

Comment: If you use an Excel table it will automatically expand as you add data.

Comment: i am trying with this and get error :
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rg_1 As Range
Dim rg_2 As Range
Dim order As Range
Dim Bestand As Range
  Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row - 6
    End With
    
    Set rg_1 = Range("W6:W" & LastRow)
    Set rg_2 = Range("X6:X" & LastRow)
    Set order = Range("W4")
    Set Bestand = Range("X4")
    order = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rg_1)
    Bestand = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rg_2)

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

After good comments from SJR (Thanks SRJ) i found this solutions that works for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Or_Menge As Range
Dim rg_1 As Range
Dim rg_2 As Range
Dim order As Range
Dim Bestand As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row - 6
    End With
    
    Set Or_Menge = Intersect(Target, Range("T6:T" & LastRow))
    
    If Or_Menge Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
    
    Else
    
    Set rg_1 = Range("W6:W" & LastRow)
    Set rg_2 = Range("X6:X" & LastRow)
    Set order = Range("W4")
    Set Bestand = Range("X4")
    order = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rg_1)
    Bestand = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rg_2)
    
    End If
    

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad you got there. You can accept your own answer I believe.